# Make, inherit rules in subdirectory Makefile

Tags: inheritance, makefile

I want to set up a system of Makefiles in my project directories so that the rules defined in one will be defined in others. Let's say for example I have a directory called "test" and inside is "test.c" but I want to build test.c using a rule defined in a Makefile in the root directory

Here is an example

```
#Makefile (inside base dir)
 %.o: %.c
   gcc -Wall -c $^

 all:
  make -C test out.a

#test/Makefile
 out.a: test.o
  ar rcs $@ $^

#test/test.c
 int main() {
   return 0;
 }

#inside root dir
$make
make -C test
make[1]: Entering directory `test'
cc    -c -o test.o test.c
/usr/ucb/cc:  language optional software package not installed
make[1]: *** [test.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `test'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Notice how it invokes cc instead of my rule using gcc defined in the root makefile.

In summary, I don't want to have to define the same rule in each Makefile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Microsoft nmake, use this:

```
!INCLUDE ..\makefile.defs
```

(assumes makefile.defs in parent dir contains the base rules)

For Gnu make, use this:

```
include ../makefile.defs
```

see http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Include.html

Answer (score 2):

You can [include](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include) one makefile into another.

Comment: The problem I have with this is that the Makefiles become path dependent. It works, but it would seem better if the rules were somehow passed to the child Make

Comment: @Mike: It's common to separate out non-path-dependent parts, like your `%.o: %.c` rule, so they can be included.  There are problems using make, which is why there are so many different alternatives.

Comment: @Mike: You might find *Recursive Make Considered Harmful* (http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) useful.